# Hexagon homomorphism with $D_6 \rightarrow S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on this problem [image: here]

I have a table set up with 6 rotations, 6 reflections and the identity so I can pair them up with the elements of $S_3$. Unfortunately I was taught $S_3$ as a set of matrices named , $\epsilon, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \kappa$ I can add their picture as well if need be. I am willing to learn another $S_3$ to better compare to $D_6$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reflection about any other axis of symmetry by first rotating, and then applying the first reflection. Hence if $\alpha$ is a rotation, and $\rho$ some reflection, most reflections should look like $\rho \alpha^n$.

As for the homomorphism, one should think of $S_3$ as bijections $\{1,2,3\}$, can you identify any geometric object with a three element set this is being permuted? (There are three ____ drawn on the picture above!)

Answer (score 0):

$S_3$ corresponds to the group of permutations of three elements.  That is, $S_3$ is the set of bijections from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself and the group action is the composition of functions.  Since each motion of the regular hexagon permutes the three diagonals, we can consider the elements of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ to correspond to the three diagonals of the hexagon and the motions can be viewed as elements of $S_3$.

Comment: Ok so this may be the wrong approach but if I consider $S_3$ and those permutations that have order 2, (if permutation can even have order, I may just be using the wrong terminology here). would the reflections correspond to those permutations since a reflection would have "order 2"?